# Error running Vitest, cannot Parse render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend, vitest

After installing vitest and writing a simple validation test im having trouble ruinning the tests.

I get this error when running vitest:

```
    FAIL  __tests__/components/Searchbar.test.js [ __tests__/components/Searchbar.test.js ]
    Error: Parse failure: Unexpected token (8:15)
    At file: C:/frontend/__tests__/components/Searchbar.test.js
    Contents of line 8:         render(<SearchBar />);
```

below is my vite.config.js:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'happy-dom',
    },
    extensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
})
```

below is my SearchBar.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function SearchBar() {
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
        />
    );
}
```

below is my SearchBar.test.js

```
import { describe, test, expect } from "vitest";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import SearchBar from "../../src/pages/components/SearchBar";


describe('SearchBar component', () => {
    test('renders the search button', () => {
        render(<SearchBar />);
        const searchInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Search...');
        expect(searchInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

how to i fix this error?

Comment: Do not post pictures of text.  Post the text itself.

Comment: you should at least post the test that is causing this error; itś impossible to analyze the error only by the message it causes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `jsx` extension to render a React component in a test. Change `SearchBar.test.js` to `SearchBar.test.jsx`